# Delete part of a column entry (dependant on the beginning of the entry)

Tags: sed

I have a file that looks like this (and millions of other lines):

```
1       rs10900604:798400:A:G   0       798400  G       A
1       rs11240777      0       798959  A       G
1       1:4970452:885689:G:A    0       885689  G       A
```

I want to change it so it looks like this:

```
1       rs10900604   0       798400  G       A
1       rs11240777      0       798959  A       G
1       1:4970452:885689:G:A    0       885689  G       A
```

So, I want to delete everything after the colon in the second column, but only if the entry in the column begins "rs..."

I have tried to do this with sed, and can remove everything after the colon with

```
sed 's/\:[0-9]*\:[A-Z]*\:[A-Z]*//g'
```

...but I can't work out how to give it specificity to the "rs..." entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be `awk` can do that easily

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /^rs/{ gsub(":.*", "", $2) }1' input
1       rs10900604 0 798400 G A
1       wrs11240777      0       798959  A       G
1       1:4970452:885689:G:A    0       885689  G       A
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, but I rarely use sed so there may be a better solution:

```
sed '/rs.*/ s/\:[0-9]*\:[A-Z]*\:[A-Z]*//' textfile.txt
```